# What is the source and authenticity of this Hadith?

Tags: hadith, hadith-interpretation, uloom-al-hadith

It is narrated by Sayyiduna Abdullah bin Umar that the Holy Prophet (sallallahu alayhi wa sallam) said:“When the belly of Makkah will be cleft open and through it will be dug out river-like passages (i.e. tunnels) and the buildings of the Holy City of Makkah will rise higher than its mountains, when you observe these signs, then understand that the time of trial(Judgment day) is near at hand.”

What is the source and authenticity of this Hadith? I read it on Quora but there was no reference given and it was cited as a prophecy about tall buildings in Mecca these days.

Comment: Have you tried searching on google? I saw a few results mentioning the sources: Naim ibn Hammad's Kitab al-Fitan and Ibn Hajar's Fath al-Bari. The prophecy about buildings is also present in some of the Al-Sihah al-Sittah.

Comment: @UmH Thanks, I found this Hadith in Musannaf Ibn Abi Shaybah  - Kitab Al-Fitan - No: 36531 - narrated by Abdullah Bin Amr (R.A).

Answer (score 3):

Ibn Hajar al-'Asqalani quoted it in his commentary on the [hadith of Anas](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/25/134) ibn Malik (on where to pray dhohr on the day of tarwiyya) as a quote of Abudllah ibn 'Omar which appears in al-Fakihi's akhbar Mekka in his fath al-Bari (see [here](https://library.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?bk_no=52&ID=1056&idfrom=3039&idto=3042&bookid=52&startno=0)).

[This fatwa](https://eshaykh.com/hadith/source-of-hadith/) says it is a saying of sahabi not a hadith and adds as sources Kitab al-Fitan of Nu'aim ibn Hammad and Gharaib al-hadith of Ibraheem al-Harbi.

Actually in al-Fakihi's akhbar Mekka there are 2 similar narrations 
on the authorithy of Abudllah ibn 'Amr ibn al-'Aas [1](https://www.islamweb.net/hadith/display_hbook.php?indexstartno=0&hflag=1&pid=112579&bk_no=175&startno=0), [2](https://www.islamweb.net/hadith/display_hbook.php?indexstartno=0&hflag=1&pid=112579&bk_no=175&startno=1) (not ibn 'Omar).

It also appears as a narration on the authority of 'Abdullah ibn 'Amr in Mosanaf ibn abi Shaybah (see [here](https://library.islamweb.net/hadith/display_hbook.php?bk_no=96&hid=36531&pid=58355) or narration#124 [here](https://library.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?bk_no=10&ID=5095&idfrom=5572&idto=5622&bookid=10&startno=5)) [on islamqa](https://islamqa.info/ar/answers/247118/%D9%87%D9%84-%D8%AB%D8%A8%D8%AA-%D9%85%D9%86-%D9%83%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85-%D8%B9%D8%A8%D8%AF-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%84%D9%87-%D8%A8%D9%86-%D8%B9%D9%85%D8%B1%D9%88-%D8%A8%D9%86-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B9%D8%A7%D8%B5-%D8%A7%D9%86-%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%AA%D9%81%D8%A7%D8%B9-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A8%D9%86%D8%A7%D8%A1-%D9%81%D9%8A-%D9%85%D9%83%D8%A9-%D9%85%D9%86-%D8%A7%D8%B4%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%B7-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B3%D8%A7%D8%B9%D8%A9) they consider the narrator chain as possibly acceptable for these kinds of informative narrations they also added that it appears in abu 'amr ad-Dani's as-Sunan al-Warida fil fitan and Musnad ibn al-Ja'ad and to some extent in Tarikh Dimashq of ibn 'Asakir via the same chain however in the later 'Abdullah ibn 'Amr was not quoted.
The chain of akhbar Mekka, al-Fitan of Nu'aim ibn Hammad and the tafssir of 'Aburrazaak and elsewhere has some issues in the narrator chain so one could consider it as weak.
A third chain was quoted in akhbar Mekka of al-Azraqi which has some discussed narrators.

Nevertheless on islamqa they come to the conclusion that this athar (they don't consider it a hadith or saying of the prophet at all) seems to have a source due to the multiple chains even if they have issues especially as there are sahih ahadith on the topic which you may find in that Arabic fatwa, here just the links (on the turn back of rivers and meadows in the Arabic peninsula in [Sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/12/76) and on the the domlishing of al-Ka'aba a version from [Sahih al-Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/25/77)).